# Делаю счетчик постов и выводит ошибку при миграции

Tags: html, python, django

Вот сама ошибка

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

models.py

```
class PageHit(models.Model):
    url = models.CharField(unique=True)
    count = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
```

decorators.py

```
from functools import wraps
from django.db.models import F
from django.db import transactions

def counted(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def decorator(request, *args, **kwargs):
        with transactions.atomic():
            counter, created = PageHit.objects.get_or_create(url=request.path)
            counter.count = F('count') + 1
            counter.save()
        return f(request, *args, **kwargs)
    return decorator
```

views.py

```
from .decorators import counted

@counted
def post_detail(request, pk):
    article = Article.objects.get(id=pk)
    return render(request, 'news/post_detail.html', {'post': article})
```

templatetags/counter.py

```
@register.simple_tag(takes_context=True)
def page_hits(ctx, page_url=None):
    counter = (PageHit.objects
                      .filter(url=(ctx['request'].path if page_url is None else page_url))
                      .first())
    return 0 if counter is None else counter.count
```

news/post_list.html

```
{% load counter %}

{% for article in object_list  %}
    <h3>{% page_hits article.get_absolute_url %}</h3>
{% endfor %}
```

news/post_detail.html

```
{% load counter %}

<span>{% page_hits %}</span>
```

Comment: Вы пытаетесь обычный декоратор применить к CBV?

Comment: Эмм нечего не понял как это исправить ? помогите пожалуйста

Comment: [Здесь](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/class-based-views/intro/#decorating-class-based-views) описаны способы.

Answer (score 0):

Вы пытаетесь сохранить в объекте модели F() значение

> ```
>     with transactions.atomic():
>         counter, created = PageHit.objects.get_or_create(url=request.path)
>         counter.count = F('count') + 1
>         counter.save()
>     return f(request, *args, **kwargs)
> ```

Так как вы работаете с объектом, то работайте с его полями и типами его полей, то есть на нужно использовать `F` объекты. Они только для `QuerySet`'ов. Просто `counter.count += 1`

---

Исправьте, и на 90% уверен, что проблема решится, ибо других замечаний по коду нет